# jQuery add function parameter or variable into id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say you have 10-15 fixed `divs` that you'd like to `animate()` with different parameters. Using jQuery, what's the best method to pass different parameters for each div? My current method, below, attempts to pass the `id` text in the `function`. This is the first step, and eventually I imagine I'd pass the `animation()` `duration` and `rotation` in as `function` `parameters` (e.g. `float(ID, duration, rotation)`It now returns the following: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#candy"`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    float("candy");
    float("candy2");
    //etc
});

function float(ID) {
    let id = "#" + ID;
    $('"' + id + '"').animate({
        top: 100,
      }, 5000 );
};
```

Comment: You are double passing quotes, causing it to respond as if you have something similar to this: ""#candy"" instead of "#candy", there is no need to do: `'"' + id + '"'` Do only $(id) and you should be fine on the error, side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the scoped variable at all. Just pass the parameters from the function call to the method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    float("candy", 5000);
    float("candy2", 2000);

});

function float(ID, duration) {
    $('#' + ID).animate({
    top: 100,
  }, duration );
};
```

```css
#candy {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  }
 #candy2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="candy"></div>
<div id="candy2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Sami. I initially did this but ran into the following error: `TypeError: $('#' + ID).animate is not a function. (In '$('#' + ID).animate({
        top: 100,
    }, duration )', '$('#' + ID).animate' is undefined)`

Comment: Are you using slim build of jQuery or the full version? The slim one doesn't include some of the functions, .animate being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the function like:

```
function float(ID) {
 let id = "#" + ID;
 $(id).animate({
    top: 100,
  }, 5000 );
}
```